# Selecting text in Sublime with ctrl and shift

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've recently started using Sublime Text and there is one thing that really grinds my gear. When selecting text by arrows with CTRL and SHIFT I came across this (for me) unexpected behavior.

Let's say for example that I have lines like that:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

And my caret is at the end of first line right after <div>. I hold CTRL + SHIFT and press RIGHT ARROW twice (one to jump to line where <p>Some text</p> is and the second to select spaces/tabs and land right before <p>Some text</p>) but the weird thing is that also  <p is getting selected.

Is there any way to configure that? I've used VS and WebStorm for a long time so this is kind of a mechanical action and this small thing in Sublime really gets me frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`**. If the file is completely empty, or just contains opening and closing square brackets `[ ]`, change the contents to the following:

```js
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": true} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": true, "extend": true} }
]
```

If you already have some custom key bindings, add the following lines to the very beginning, on the line just after the opening bracket `[`:

```js
    { "keys": ["ctrl+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": true} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": true, "extend": true} },
```

Make sure you save the file when you're done. This will give you the behavior you're used to.